# How to properly migrate to effector from redux, keeping actions pure and isolated?

Tags: reactjs, redux, effector

I've decided to try [`effector`](https://effector.dev/) and I'm trying to figure out the best way to replace redux in my project with it.

Whenever I use redux in a React project, I usually have the following structure for a feature:

```
src
└── features
    └── some_feature
        ├── components
        │   └── MyComponent
        │       └── index.ts
        └── redux
            ├── actions.ts
            ├── types.ts
            └── reducer.ts
```

With the said, here is how my files would look like:

```
// src/features/some_feature/components/MyComponent/index.ts
import * as React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { someFunction } from '../../redux/actions';

const MyComponent: React:FC = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(someFunction());
    }, [])

    return <div>My component!</div>
}
```

My actions:

```
// src/features/some_feature/redux/actions.ts
import { httpClient } from 'src/services/httpClient';
import { SOME_ACTION } from '../types';

type TSetSomeData = {
    payload: {
        someData: any;
    }
}
const setSomeData = ({ payload: { someData } }): ThunkAction =>
    (dispatch): void => {
        dispatch({
            type: SOME_ACTION,
            payload: someData
        })
    };

export const someFunction = (): ThunkAction =>
    async (dispatch): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const { someData } = (await httpClient({
                url: '/api/some-endpoint',
                method: EMethodTypes.GET,
            })) as {
                someData: any;
            };

            dispatch(setSomeData({ payload: { someData } }));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error in someFunction', err);
        }
    };
```

My reducer:

```
// src/features/some_feature/redux/reducer.ts
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { SOME_ACTION } from './types';

export type ISomeFeatureState = {
    someData: any;
};

const initialState = {
    someData: null,
};

const someFeatureReducer = (state: ISomeFeatureState = initialState, action: AnyAction): ISomeFeatureState => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    if (type === SOME_ACTION) {
        return {
            ...state,
            someData: payload,
        };
    } else {
        return {
            ...state,
        };
    }
};

export default someFeatureReducer;
```

And `types.ts` would have `export const SOME_ACTION = '@redux/features/some_feature/some-action'`.

Anyway, here is how my folder structure looks like now:

```
src
└── features
    └── some_feature
        ├── components
        │   └── MyComponent
        │       └── index.ts
        └── effector
            ├── actions.ts
            ├── events.ts
            └── store.ts
```

And here are the files:

```
// src/features/some_feature/effector/store.ts
import { createStore } from 'effector';

export const $someData = createStore(null, {
    updateFilter: (someData) => !!someData,
});
```

```
// src/features/some_feature/effector/events.ts
import { $someData } from './store';

export const setSomeDataEvent = createEvent();
$someData.on(setSomeDataEvent, (state, payload) => payload);
```

```
// src/features/some_feature/effector/actions.ts
import { setSomeDataEvent } from './events';

type TSetSomeData = {
    payload: {
        someData: any;
    };
};
export const setSomeData = ({ payload: { someData } }: TSetSomeData) => {
    setSomeDataEvent(someData);
};
```

So, it's already cleaner and less code. The reason I've chosen such a structure and approach, is because it is very similar to my existing structure.

Anyway, effector offers different ways of mutating stores, one of which is on `doneData`:

```
// from the docs

import { createEvent, createStore, createEffect, sample } from 'effector'

const nextPost = createEvent()

const getCommentsFx = createEffect(async postId => {
  const url = `posts/${postId}/comments`
  const base = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
  const req = await fetch(`${base}/${url}`)
  return req.json()
})

const $postComments = createStore([])
  .on(getCommentsFx.doneData, (_, comments) => comments)

const $currentPost = createStore(1)
  .on(getCommentsFx.done, (_, {params: postId}) => postId)

sample({
  source: $currentPost,
  clock: nextPost,
  fn: postId => postId + 1,
  target: getCommentsFx,
})

nextPost()
```

Here, once `getCommentsFx` finishes executing, the value for the store `$postComments` is set with whatever `getCommentsFx.doneData` resolves to.

What I'm having trouble with, is utilizing the same approach, but making it "friendly" with my current project.

The only way that I can think of, is rewriting `someFunction` like this:

```
// src/features/some_feature/effector/actions.ts
import { createEffect } from 'effector';
import { httpClient } from 'src/services/httpClient';
import { $someData } from '../store';
import { setSomeDataEvent } from '../events';

type TSetSomeData = {
    payload: {
        someData: any;
    }
}
export const setSomeData = ({ payload: { someData } }: TSetSomeData) => {
    setSomeDataEvent(someData);
};
    

export const someFunction = (): ThunkAction =>
    async (dispatch): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const { someData } = await createEffect<{someData: any}>(async () =>
                httpClient({
                    url: '/api/some-endpoint',
                    method: EMethodTypes.GET,
                })
            );

            setSomeDataEvent(someData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error in someFunction', err);
        }
    };
```

But I see no point in using `createEffect` at all, because I can just do this:

```
export const someFunction = (): ThunkAction =>
    async (dispatch): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const { someData } = (await httpClient({
                url: '/api/some-endpoint',
                method: EMethodTypes.GET,
            })) as {
                someData: any
            }

            setSomeDataEvent(someData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error in someFunction', err);
        }
    };
```

Any suggestions about going about this? Is it fine to use `effector` without `createEffect` (or most other provided methods via its API, for that matter)? Essentially, I'm just creating stores and binding events to them, I feel like I'm not using `effector` in the way it was intended, but I can't think of a better way to rewrite it.

What can I do here? Should I just got back to Redux?

Answer (score 1):

You should'n create effects inside a functions, because it is not performable and may cause memory lacks

Using your code snippet you can create effect

```
import { createEffect } from "effector";

type SomeDataType = any;
type Input = void;
type Output = { someData: SomeDataType };

const fetchSomeDataFx = createEffect<Input, Output>(async () => {
  return await httpClient({
    url: '/api/some-endpoint',
    method: EMethodTypes.GET,
  })
})
```

P.S. if you need to debug this effect, you can use `debug` from `patronum` library

```
import { debug } from "patronum";

debug(fetchSomeDataFx);
```

If you need to display information about fails http request you can use

```
import { createStore } from "effector";

export const $fetchSomeDataError = createStore<Error | null>(null)
  .reset(fetchSomeDataFx)
  .on(fetchSomeDataFx.failData, (_, error) => error);
```

And attach this effect to store

```
import { sample, createStore } from "effector";

export const $someData = createStore<SomeDataType | null>(null);

sample({
  source: fetchSomeDataFx.doneData,
  fn: (doneData) => doneData.someData,
  target: $someData
})
```

Hope it helps to you!